# Return a value asynchronously acquired in a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, logic

This can be considered a general programming question or even logic question, as it's language independent.

I have the following piece of code in JavaScript:

```
...
{text: 'Modelo', dataIndex: 'model', filterable: true,
    renderer: function(value) {

        // this will asynchronously load the object "Model" from the database which have primary key equals to "value".
        MyApp.model.Model.load(value, {
            scope: this,
            success: function(record, operation) {
                // this will be executed if succeeded. I need to return the "record" parameter in the outer function.
            }
        });
        return value; // There must be a way to return the "record" parameter from above.
    }
}, 
...
```

As stated in the comments, there's the outer function `renderer` that calls an inner asynchronous function `load` that retrieves the value `record` I need to return from the outer function.

I tried ugly things like an empty `while`-loop waiting for a variable declared in the outer function to be set in the inner function and then return it, but no success, the loop ended up being infinite.

Comment: See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call). Short answer: you can't return the value, use a callback or promises.

Comment: Why there must always be a downvote? I don't know why I keep returning to this website to ask for help, I am asking a legitimate question and downvoting only makes me feel that it's a stupid question and that people are less willing to help. Remember what teachers said back in school? _Don't be afraid to ask_. This website is not like this. That's why I am sure the old "forum" style ask-and-answer worked better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return directly as the `success` callback fires after the return has occurred. Instead you can continue this callback pattern in your code... if you change the function signature of `renderer` to accept a callback:

```
{text: 'Modelo', dataIndex: 'model', filterable: true,
    renderer: function(value, successCb) {    
        MyApp.model.Model.load(value, {
            scope: this,
            success: function(record, operation) {
                if(successCb){
                    successCb(record, operation);
                }
            }
        });
        //return void, and communicate back to the caller using successCb above.
    }
},
```

and the caller of `renderer` supplies a callback:

```
myObj.renderer(someVal,function(rec,op){
    //do something
});
```

now you can get data out of your function asynchronously.